# Why is my data from my input field inputting all previous data input into my spreadsheet?

Tags: python, excel

i am trying to get data from a text box to an excel document, i have this working but the only problem is that it adds the previous data submitted along with the data in the text box
Here is the get data code and the delete code I'm using.

```
def clear():
    
    # clear the content of text entry box
    name_field.delete(0, END)
    build_field.delete(0, END)
    price_field.delete(0, END)
    contact_no_field.delete(0, END)
    email_id_field.delete(0, END)
    address_field.delete(0, END)

def insert():
    
    # if user not fill any entry
    # then print "empty input"
    if (name_field.get() == "" and
        build_field.get() == "" and
        price_field.get() == "" and
        contact_no_field.get() == "" and
        email_id_field.get() == "" and
        address_field.get() == ""):
            
        print("empty input")

    else:

        # assigning the max row and max column
        # value upto which data is written
        # in an excel sheet to the variable
        current_row = sheet.max_row
        current_column = sheet.max_column

        # get method returns current text
        # as string which we write into
        # excel spreadsheet at particular location
        sheet.cell(row=current_row + 1, column=3).value = name_field.get()
        sheet.cell(row=current_row + 1, column=5).value = build_field.get()
        sheet.cell(row=current_row + 1, column=9).value = price_field.get()
        sheet.cell(row=current_row + 1, column=6).value = contact_no_field.get()
        sheet.cell(row=current_row + 1, column=7).value = email_id_field.get()
        sheet.cell(row=current_row + 1, column=8).value = address_field.get()
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the value inside a variable 1st then from variable to cell. This way you can clear the variable for each prompt and not just clearing the text box

```
name_field.delete(0, END)
nameValue = None
nameValue = name_field.get()
sheet.cell(row=current_row + 1, column=3).value = nameValue
```